# Guards on "Nothing" Setting

Tags: haskell

UPDATE:

To be fair, my example was a simplification of a problem I'm facing, I've tried implementing the solution, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
followConnection :: Connection->Crib->Stecker->Offsets->Maybe Stecker
followConnection w x y z
| steckerAdd ((enigmaEncode (getSndTripleEl w) (SimpleEnigma rotor1 rotor2 rotor3 reflectorB) (calculateOffset z (getFirstTripleEl w))), (getThirdTripleEl w)) y == Nothing = Nothing
| steckerAdd ((enigmaEncode (getSndTripleEl w) (SimpleEnigma rotor1 rotor2 rotor3 reflectorB) (calculateOffset z (getFirstTripleEl w))), (getThirdTripleEl w)) y == Just (y) = y
```

With

```
 steckerAdd ((enigmaEncode (getSndTripleEl w) (SimpleEnigma rotor1 rotor2 rotor3 reflectorB) (calculateOffset z (getFirstTripleEl w))), (getThirdTripleEl w)) y == Just (y) = y
```

Giving

Couldn't match type `[(Char, Char)]' with`Maybe Stecker'
 Expected type: Maybe Stecker
   Actual type: Stecker

I have a function (myFunction) which returns "Maybe Int" as an output

I would like to code something similar to:

```
myOtherFunction :: Int -> Maybe Int
myOtherFunction x
| myFunction x == Nothing = 1
| myFunction x == 1 = 2
| otherwise = 3
```

However, Haskell doesn't seem to like me comparing a "Maybe Int" value to an int...

I also tried "casting" it to an Int by making it:

```
| fromMaybe(myFunction) x == 1 = 2
```

Where the function is:

```
fromMaybe :: Maybe a -> a
fromMaybe (Just x)=x
```

Ideas?

Comment: Why not `myFunction x == Just 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should use instead is pattern matching:

```
myOtherFunction :: Maybe Int -> Int
myOtherFunction Nothing = 1
myOtherFunction (Just 1) = 2
myOtherFunction _ = 3
```

The reason why yours doesn't work is because you can't compare an `Int` directly to a `Maybe Int`.  This is true in any language, not just Haskell.  Comparing two different types usually doesn't work.

---

If you really wanted to use guards, you could do

```
myOtherFunction :: Int -> Maybe Int
myOtherFunction x
    | myFunction x == Nothing = 1
    | myFunction x == Just 1 = 2
    | otherwise = 3
```

Comment: To be fair, my example was a simplification of a problem I'm facing, I've tried implementing the solution, but it doesn't seem to work...

followConnection :: Connection->Crib->Stecker->Offsets->Maybe Stecker
followConnection w x y z
    | steckerAdd ((enigmaEncode (getSndTripleEl w) (SimpleEnigma rotor1 rotor2 rotor3 reflectorB) (calculateOffset z (getFirstTripleEl w))), (getThirdTripleEl w)) y == Nothing = Nothing
    | steckerAdd ((enigmaEncode (getSndTripleEl w) (SimpleEnigma rotor1 rotor2 rotor3 reflectorB) (calculateOffset z (getFirstTripleEl w))), (getThirdTripleEl w)) y == Just (y) =y

Comment: The problem in your definition is that the result types would be different. If your second equation you're returning something of type `Stecker` and in the first one something of type `Maybe a`. Thus, it doesn't type check. You have to either: create a partial function which returns a `Stecker` by dropping the first equation; or wrap the result in the second equation with `Just`. In this second case, then `folowConnection w x y z` is equivalent to the big application you have in the guards.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume that your `myFunction` has this type:

```
myFunction :: Int -> Maybe Int
```

I'm also going to assume that you wrote the type of `myOtherFunction` incorrectly, since it produces an `Int` result and not a `Maybe Int`:

```
myOtherFunction :: Int -> Int
```

The way you do this is pattern matching, which you write using a `case` statement:

```
myOtherFunction x = case (myFunction x) of
    Nothing -> 1
    Just 1  -> 2
    _       -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
myOtherFunction :: Int -> Maybe Int
myOtherFunction x
 | myFunction x == Nothing = 1
 | myFunction x == Just 1 = 2
 | otherwise = 3
```

[Here's an Ideone of this kind of thing.](http://ideone.com/oCQ0hK)

Answer (score 0):

The 4th line of your updated example ends with `= y`. But it is clear from `followConnection`'s type signature that `y` is a `Stecker`, and not a `Maybe Steker`.

Try changing the end of that 4th line to `= Just y`. This is most likely what the error is referring to, since it expects a `Maybe Stecker` to be returned, but it is getting a `Stecker`.